# After the user click search button the map doesn't show where is the error?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, mysql

I have a **PHP** code with **MYSQL** database, **HTML** and **javascript**  with **CSS**  where this code make the user select from the dropdown list and based on the user input the system will display a table that contains info related to requested data and it will pop up Google map that has a marker to show the location.

the problem is that after the user clicks the search button the system display the table without the Google map.

I do not know if the problem is in the **CSS** or in the **javascript** code

## CSS code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Custom Markers</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=xxxxx&callback=initMap">
    </script>

     <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 400px;
        width:1045px;
        float: right;


      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;

      }
       #form {
              background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #CCCCCC, #EEEEEE 175px);
              background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #CCCCCC, #EEEEEE 175px);
              background: linear-gradient(bottom, #CCCCCC, #EEEEEE 175px);
              margin: auto;
              width: 550px;
              height: 450px;
              position: absolute;


              font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
              font-size: 14px;
              font-style: italic;
              line-height: 24px;
              font-weight: bold;
              color: #09C;
              text-decoration: none;
              border-radius: 10px;
              padding: 10px;
              border: 1px solid #999;
              border: inset 1px solid #333;
             -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
             -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
             box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
           }

    </style>
```

## JavaScript CODE:

```
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
 <script type="text/javascript">

         var map,currentPopup;
         function initMap() 
         {
         map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 8,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(33.888630, 35.495480),
          mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
         });
       }
        function addMarker(feature) {
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: feature.position,

            //icon: icons[feature.type].icon,
            map: map
          });



          var popup = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                   content: '<b>Location :</b> ' + feature.info +'<br></br>' 
                   + '<b>Coordinates :</b> '+ feature.position +'<br></br>'
                   + '<b> Frequency :</b>' + feature.Frequency +'<br></br>',  
                   maxWidth: 300
                });

          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
                    if (currentPopup != null) 
                    {
                        currentPopup.close();
                        currentPopup = null;
                    }
                    popup.open(map, marker);
                    currentPopup = popup;
                });
                google.maps.event.addListener(popup, "closeclick", function() {
                    map.panTo(center);
                    currentPopup = null;
                });
        }

        var features = [
        <?php
            $prependStr ="";
            foreach( $wpdb->get_results("select l.locationName, l.lattitude, l.longitude, f.TX, f.RX
                                       FROM army_site_location l LEFT 
                                       JOIN army_frequencies f
                                         on l.siteID = f.siteID 
                                       where l.locationName = '".$site_name."'", OBJECT) as $key => $row) {
               $lattitude = $row->lattitude;
               $longitude = $row->longitude;
               $TX = $row->TX;
               $RX = $row->RX;
               $siteName = $row->locationName;
           echo $prependStr;


       ?>
{
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $latitude; ?>, <?php echo $longitude; ?>),
    info:'<?php echo $siteName;?>',
    Frequency: '<?php echo $TX;?>','<?php echo $RX;?>'


}
<?php
$prependStr =",";
}
?>
        ];



        for (var i = 0, feature; feature = features[i]; i++) {



          addMarker(feature);
       }

}

        </script>
```

## HTML code

```
<div id="form">
    <form method ="post" action ="" name="submit_form">
        <table border="0" width="30%">
            <tr>
               <td>Site Location</td>
               <td>employee Name</td>
               <td>Inspection Date</td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
               <td><select id="site_locationID"  name = "site_locationName">
                      <option value="">Select Site</option>
                 <?php



                     $query_site_location =$wpdb->get_results("Select DISTINCT
                      l.locationName,
                      e.employeeID,
                      e.employeeName,
                      i.inspectionID,
                      i.inspectionDate
                      FROM
                      army_site_location l 
                      JOIN inspection_site s
                      ON
                      s.siteID = l.siteID
                     JOIN inspection_info i 
                     ON
                     i.inspectionID = s.inspectionID
                     JOIN employee e 
                     ON
                     e.employeeID = i.employeeID");

                     //echo $query_site_location;

                      foreach($query_site_location as $row)
                      {





echo "<option id = '".$row ->employeeName."' name = '".$row ->inspectionDate."' id2 = '".$row ->employeeID."' name2 = '".$row ->inspectionID."' '".$row ->locationName."'>".$row->locationName."</option>";



                      } 




                 ?>

                </select></td>
                <!--create  dropdown list owner names-->
                <td><select id="employee_nameID"  name ="soldier_nameName">
                <option value="">Select Soldier</option>
                </select></td>

               <!--create  dropdown list Company names-->
                <td><select id="inspection_dateID"  name ="inspection_dateNAME">
                <option value="">Select Date</option>
                </select></td>

       </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type ="submit" name="query_submit" value ="Search" /></td>
      </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
  </div><!-- div of the  form-->
```

Comment: I don't see any code where you actually receive the search form data and do anything with it!?

Comment: the system received the data in 2 ways javascript for the Google map and markers.
and through PHP for creating table that includes all related information.
i did not add the PHP part

Answer (score 0):

Try this let me know.....

You call `addMarker` function when initialize the map....

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var map,currentPopup;
    var features = [
    <?php
        $prependStr ="";
        foreach( $wpdb->get_results("select l.locationName, l.lattitude, l.longitude, f.TX, f.RX FROM army_site_location l LEFT JOIN army_frequencies f  on l.siteID = f.siteID where l.locationName = '".$site_name."'", OBJECT) as $key => $row) {
            $lattitude = $row->lattitude;
            $longitude = $row->longitude;
            $TX = $row->TX;
            $RX = $row->RX;
            $siteName = $row->locationName;
            echo $prependStr;
    ?>
        {
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $latitude; ?>, <?php echo $longitude; ?>),
            info:'<?php echo $siteName;?>',
            Frequency: '<?php echo $TX;?>','<?php echo $RX;?>'
        }
    <?php
            $prependStr =",";
        }
    ?>


    function initMap()
    {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 8,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(33.888630, 35.495480),
            mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
        });

        for (var i = 0;i<features.length; i++) {
            addMarker(features[i]);
        }
    }
    function addMarker(feature) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: feature.position,

            //icon: icons[feature.type].icon,
            map: map
        });
        var popup = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: '<b>Location :</b> ' + feature.info +'<br></br>'
            + '<b>Coordinates :</b> '+ feature.position +'<br></br>'
            + '<b> Frequency :</b>' + feature.Frequency +'<br></br>',
            maxWidth: 300
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
            if (currentPopup != null)
            {
                currentPopup.close();
                currentPopup = null;
            }
            popup.open(map, marker);
            currentPopup = popup;
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(popup, "closeclick", function() {
            map.panTo(center);
            currentPopup = null;
        });
    }


</script>
```

Comment: i tried your answer and it did not work 
my javascript code make Google Map to be displayed at the initialization but when the user click the search button it disappear ... your code doesn't show the Google Map AT ALL

Comment: Initially showing google map, is it correct? If yes then search something, it goes to ajax or page loading?